How can I make DrawerLayour Activity scrollable in Android Studio?
I have a DrawerLayout activity which is the part of a navigation drawer. And I have to put a lot of buttons in it, but it seems it doesn't scroll. So I want to make it scrollable. How can I make it?
This is the code:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
tools:context=".Floor1Activity">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button114"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/lavender"
        android:onClick="go_122"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:paddingBottom="25dp"
        android:text="122"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
    
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_gravity = "start">
    <include
        layout="@layout/nav_drawer"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout >`

I tried to put ScrollView tag to every place that is possible, but it doesn't work.
